# How to reliably fill a long thin tube with insulating expanding foam

Tags: insulation, windows

I have several bay window frames each having two long thin hollow uPVC tubes about 1.3 metres long x 3.5 cm diameter (4' 3" x 1 3/8 inch).  They are hollow with no interior insulation and in the winter they get cold and condensation forms, so I'd like to insulate them by filling them with expanding foam.

I'm conscious that good thermal insulation requires avoiding gaps as much as possible.  I suspect it would be easy to end up with for example the top half filled with foam and the bottom half empty.

Since the tubes are installed already, I can only easily access the open end at the top.  Conceivably I could drill a small hole at the bottom, but only a small one maybe 1 cm diameter at the most - bigger would be hard to cover up.

How can I reliably fill up the whole tube without gaps?

Comment: Use a longer tube for the foam for filling.  Have you thought of using a solid foam tube instead and stuffing it down.

Comment: You might want to do a flame test on that expanding foam before you decide to embed it in already-plastic windows.  I would also consult with the window manufacturer as the expanding part of expanding foam may create problems like bind the window.

Comment: Polystyrene balls, and then reseal ?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks, what do you mean by "bind" the window?  Also, why a flame test?  This part of the window is not near any ignition source, and I don't know why this location would be more dangerous than any other?  The window manufacturer is unknown to me.

Comment: @crip659 Yes, that did occur to me, but I don't know how I'd source a solid but flexible thermally insulating foam tube of just the right diameter.

Comment: A window that binds is a window that doesn't go up or down very well.  Some people want to understand the flammability of building materials you use in your home, and in particular the toxicity of the smoke. People being incapacitated by breathing toxics (e.g. cyanide) in the smoke is a huge source of fire fatalities in recent years.  It's possible that spray foam is not suitable for *any* location in your home, particularly the aerosol can variety. Weighing convenience vs safety is up to you.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica . The tube is between window frames rather than part of them so I think isn't likely to cause binding unless I manage to significantly expand the tube itself.  Good point about flammability.